# using required=False, still getting required field error

Tags: python, django

I have a form class which takes a model, meta class of the form is as below,
the problem is that I want to make the patient_signature and worker_signature fields unrequired, I tried removing the class wide required_css_class but that did not help, giving each attribute classes required as True/False is also not helping.

Any suggestions...?

```
class Meta:
        model = Locator
        exclude = ('patient','worker', 'mode_of_transmission', 'secondary_telephone_number', 'locator', 'grant', 'thumbnail')
        creation_date=forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today,
                                      widget=SelectDateWidget(),
                                      label="Creation Date")
        patient_signature=forms.CharField(widget=ClientSignatureWidget())
        worker_signature=forms.CharField(widget=WorkerSignatureWidget())
        required_css_class = 'required'
```

Comment: @Daniel Roseman answer is correct, but if you would like to set required to False on every ModelForm for Locator you could just set blank=True on the field patient_signature (at the model level).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/), you cannot override the fields *inside* the `Meta` class. It must be outside.

Also, if the field is required in the model but not in the form, then you *must* provide a default value, like this:

```
class LocatorForm:
    patient_signature = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=" ")

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Alternatively, do not mention that field in the `fields` list and set a value by overriding the submission of the form's POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
patient_signature=forms.CharField(widget=ClientSignatureWidget(), required=False)
```

Comment: This is not working, the field is still giving error that this is a mandatory field.